# Cohen's d in R with negative pre to post mean change

Tags: r

Using cohen's d in R to calculate effect sizes for matched group of respondents. In some cases, the post means are lower than the pre means. In these instances, the effect size is being reported as positive. Is this possible or have I not executed the function properly?

The script is set up as follows:

```
library(lsr) 
cohensD(TPD$PreQ2a, TPD$PostQ2a, method="paired")
```

---

Comment: Size is just size, not direction.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong.  If you check the documentation via `?cohensD`, it says

**Value**

Numeric variable containing the effect size, d.  Note that it does not show the direction of the effect, only the magnitude.  That is, the value of d returned by the function is always positive or zero.